# Slow nuget restore/update/install in Rider while using private repository

Tags: nuget, artifactory, rider

Whenever I need to update or install a nuget package from a private repository, Rider is trying to get every already restored package in my solution from that repository. This is making this process extremely slow.

[image: Background Tasks in Rider]